# Face authentication using React native keychain in Android

Tags: android, react-native, biometrics, android-biometric, react-native-keychain

I'm trying to set and get data using react native keychain library with below options:

```
accessControl: ACCESS_CONTROL.BIOMETRY_ANY,

accessible: ACCESSIBLE.WHEN_UNLOCKED
```

I was successfully set the data. When I'm trying to retrieve data using Fingerprint, it's working fine for me. But when I trying to retrieve data using Face recognition, always getting an error as follows: `[Error: Wrapped error: User not authenticated]`.

This scenario happened only in the Android device. In iOS devices, it's working correctly. I'm using the same face which I used to unlock my device.

This issue is already open in the Github repository. you can find it here: https://github.com/oblador/react-native-keychain/issues/318

Please let me know If you have any solution or workaround to resolve this issue.

Device Info:

```
Name: realme 5

Model: RMX1911

Android Version: 10
```

Comment: Hi Milan, were you able to get this working?